# Jenkins: Trigger a downstream project in pipeline view using REST Webservices

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, build-pipeline-plugin

I have a Jenkins pipeline with several projects. The first one triggers the second one and then it stops because the next project is manually triggered. I would like to trigger this third project using a REST Webservice. [I can manually trigger this project using the build pipeline plugin icon (trigger).]

Jenkins has a REST API to build a project: JENKINS/view/PIPELINE_NAME/job/PROJECT_NAME/buildWithParameters

However, jenkins starts a new build outside the pipeline view.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm in the same situation and looking for a solution.

Comment: Same here, I am looking with a possibilities to manually set dependencies via groovy. Haven't resolved yet.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32183061/jenkins-build-pipeline-plugin-doesnt-reflect-manually-triggered-downstream-job that's mine (a bit different but related)

Answer (score 0):

curious to know.. anybody figured out this ?

-Sony Koithara

Comment: You are not answering that question, please use comments if you actually want to comment something or upvote question to empasize that you are interested in answer.